Why did Kingpin blame Miles for the loss of his family?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Kingpin confronts Miles, even though his family died in a car accident.

Kingpin: You took my family. And now I'm gonna make sure you never see
yours again.

Why did Kingpin blame Miles for the loss of his family?

Miles disrupted the dimensional machine that Kingpin was using to pull in copies of his deceased family. As a result, Kingpin now blames him for not having those family members.

+1. Now it makes real sense.
